# Should redirects / rewrites be done in Traefik or IIS URL Rewrite when using Docker?

Tags: docker

I've been involved with a Sitecore upgrade from 8 to 10.2 using Docker. We have some issues with the existing rewrites (such as lowercasing URLs) in the web.config where the site is redirecting to http rather than staying on HTTPS as before.

I'm trying to work out if these kind of settings should be done at the Traefik level or if URL Rewrite is still the tool for the job.

Comment: What behavior should remain the same if/when you deploy outside of your local dev setup?

Comment: It really depends on your environment setup. Many Sitecore Docker solutions don't use Traefik in production. Are you planning to use Traefik in all your environments, is this hosted in a public cloud?

Comment: The rules were the same for local, test, and prod environments on v8, so this will likely still be the case once upgraded. The production technical design hasn't been done yet, but will be on Sitecore cloud.